# If an exception is thrown in the catch clause, does finally still run

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Considering the below code, does finally still run if there was an exception thrown in the catch clause?

```
try {
//code here throws exception
}
catch(Exception ex) {
//code catches above exception however code here also throws another exception
}
finally {
//does this code even run considering the exception thrown in the above catch clause??
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between finally and no finally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834175/what-is-the-difference-between-finally-and-no-finally)

Comment: It seems to me you could replace the comments in your question with a line or two of code and test this yourself. You'd get an answer much faster, and might learn a thing or two extra in the process. :)

Comment: Yes, duplicate of and answered excellently by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5834290/712765) to "What is the difference between finally and no finally?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it does. It runs regardless of what happens in the try/catch (assuming the JVM doesn't shut down for some reason)